# What goes wrong in my array comparison code?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic, comparison

My array comparison function works fine when I feed it with multiple values.
But when both arrays contain only one value it does not work correct.

Working comparison script:

```
<%
Function InArray(Needle, Haystack)
    Dim i, x
    InArray = False
    If UBound(Haystack)>0 Then
        For i = 0 To Ubound(Haystack)
            If IsArray(Needle) = True Then
                For x = 0 To Ubound(Needle)
                    If Trim(Haystack(i)) = Trim(Needle(x)) Then
                        InArray = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                If Trim(Haystack(i)) = Trim(Needle) Then
                    InArray = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next
    end if  
End Function

Dim HRMarray: HRMarray=array(459,14,2345)
Dim ADSarray: ADSarray=array(459,123,14,3345)

For Each HRMemployee In HRMarray
    If (inarray(HRMemployee,ADSarray) = False)  then
        response.write HRMemployee& " missing in ADSarray <br>" 
    end if
Next

For Each ADSemployee In ADSarray
    If (inarray(ADSemployee,HRMarray) = False)  then
        response.write ADSemployee& " to much in ADSarray <br>" 
    end if
Next
%>
```

Oke output:

2345 missing in ADSarray 
123 to much in ADSarray  
3345 to much in ADSarray

Not working comparison script:

```
<%
Function InArray(Needle, Haystack)
    Dim i, x
    InArray = False
    If UBound(Haystack)>0 Then
        For i = 0 To Ubound(Haystack)
            If IsArray(Needle) = True Then
                For x = 0 To Ubound(Needle)
                    If Trim(Haystack(i)) = Trim(Needle(x)) Then
                        InArray = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                If Trim(Haystack(i)) = Trim(Needle) Then
                    InArray = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next
    end if  
End Function

Dim HRMarray: HRMarray=array(459)
Dim ADSarray: ADSarray=array(459)

For Each HRMemployee In HRMarray
    If (inarray(HRMemployee,ADSarray) = False)  then
        response.write HRMemployee& " missing in ADSarray <br>" 
    end if
Next

For Each ADSemployee In ADSarray
    If (inarray(ADSemployee,HRMarray) = False)  then
        response.write ADSemployee& " to much in ADSarray <br>" 
    end if
Next
%>
```

NOK output:

459 missing in ADSarray  
459 to much in ADSarray

This output is not oke because both arrays are containing the same content so it should not give any output at all.

I hope someone sees what goes wrong here.

Regards,

Frans

Comment: Ubound of an an array with 1 element = 0. That should be easy enough to spot if you just debug your script. Why do you even test for Ubound > 0? That does not make any sense. Just remove the test.

Answer (score 2):

Omit the `If UBound(Haystack)>0 Then` line (and the corresponding `end if` as well), or change it to `If UBound(Haystack) >= 0 Then`.

Explanation: the `UBound` function returns `0` for a one-element array, and `-1` for an empty one (no-element array).

A proof using the following test script:

```
option explicit
Dim HRMarray: HRMarray=array(459)
Dim ADSarray: ADSarray=array()
Dim strRes
strRes = _
    UBound( HRMarray) & vbTab & varType( HRMarray) & vbTab & typeName( HRMarray) _
  & vbNewLine _
  & UBound( ADSarray) & vbTab & varType( ADSarray) & vbTab & typeName( ADSarray)
Wscript.Echo strRes
```

Result:

```
==> cscript .\SO\56611737a.vbs
```

> ```
> 0       8204    Variant()
> -1      8204    Variant()
> ```

Comment: Dear JosefZ, Thank you for an excelent sollution to my problem and th very complete answer and explanation.

Comment: @Frans If this answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.